# How to do cumsum of 2 groups by dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, cumsum

I wrote  the following code:

```
set.seed(20)
dat <- data.frame(item=c(rep("i1", 10), rep("i2", 10)),
                  choice=c(sample(1:4, 20, replace = TRUE)))
```

I need to get the cumulative sums of each choice by the 2 item:

```
  item  choice     n     cumsum  
1 i1         1     2          2
2 i1         2     3          5
3 i1         3     1          6
4 i1         4     4         10
5 i2         1     3          3
6 i2         2     3          6
7 i2         3     2          8
8 i2         4     2         10
```

I wrote:

```
dat %>% 
  group_by(item, choice) %>% 
  count() %>% 
  mutate(n) %>%
  mutate(cum=cumsum(n))
```

And get:

```
  item  choice     n   cum
  <fct>  <int> <int> <int>
1 i1         1     2     2
2 i1         2     3     3
3 i1         3     1     1
4 i1         4     4     4
5 i2         1     3     3
6 i2         2     3     3
7 i2         3     2     2
8 i2         4     2     2
```

How should I modify my code to get what I need?

Comment: @docendodiscimus turns out `n` isn't in `dat`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you just need

```
dat %>% 
  group_by(item, choice) %>% 
  summarize(n=n()) %>% 
  mutate(cum = cumsum(n))
```

Comment: Another option is to replace `summarize(n=n()) %>%` with `tally %>%`

Answer (score 1):

You have grouped your data by `item` and `choice`. In order to get the cumulative sum per `item`, just use group it by `item` after you have summarised the data:

```
dat %>% 
  group_by(item, choice) %>% 
  count() %>% 
  group_by(item) %>% 
  mutate(cum=cumsum(n))
```

This will return:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 4
# Groups:   item [2]
  item  choice     n   cum
  <fct>  <int> <int> <int>
1 i1         1     2     2
2 i1         2     3     5
3 i1         3     1     6
4 i1         4     4    10
5 i2         1     3     3
6 i2         2     3     6
7 i2         3     2     8
8 i2         4     2    10
```